# Is it possible to detect keystate generally when focusing on a browser from an outside context?

Tags: javascript, browser

I have a web application that can cause confusing behavior in the edge case where a user is holding the shift key down when they focus on a different OS window, then release shift, then focus back on the web application in the browser. My browser still thinks the user's holding shift down, even tho they're not because of how it keeps track of keystate.

I know that many events have the shift keystate attached, and so i can hook into that. But what if I care about other keys like 'wasd'? Is there a general way to figure out that the key is no longer being pressed in this case?

Comment: why don't you detect if the page loses focus.

Comment: @epascarello That's a great idea! But there will still be edge cases there, like if someone holds down a key, then clicks on the browser to focus on it.